# Runnable should start only one time

Tags: runnable

how can I prevent the runnable from being started a second time when the app is restarted? The  runnable sends messages out at a certain interval.

I've been working with SharedPrefrences and it doesn't work because the runnable's termination isn't auditable.

Comment: Can you record the start of the runnable instead of it's termination and use that?

Comment: Which runnable are you talking about? Any code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution now. The runnable saves the current timemillis in sharedpreferences every second and the new instance of the app can check whether the timemillis are more than one second ago. this determines whether the runnable is still running or not.